# add a node in document in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am trying to remove and add similar nodes in a document tree

```
Element firstItem = (Element) links.item(0);
Element element = (Element)firstItem.cloneNode(true);
int length = links.getLength();
while (0 != length) {
    System.out.println("removing element #" + l + " Length: " + length);
    Element link1 = (Element) links.item(0);
    Element parentElm = (Element) link1.getParentNode();
    parentElm.removeChild(link1);
    length--;
}

// this gives a null pointer exception           
doc.getParentNode().insertBefore(element, null);
```

what would be the ideal way to add element to doc ? the remove loop works fine

Comment: No actually i need something like <root>
<elem attrsn="1">
<sub>Good</sub>
</elem>
<root>

what i want to do is take the entire <elem></elem> and change the attributes and texts and add undefined number of nodes. i just need one node for reference, which i change attributes and add to the doc. i am first cloning the 0th <elem> and deleting all <elem>s. then while add doc.appendChild(changedElem) i get exception sequence error, something like that

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will add an element:

```
Element newElement = doc.createElement("foo");
parentElm.appendChild(newElement);
```

This will create a new child element `<foo/>` and will only work if the `parentElm` is from the same document as `doc`.  There's also a namespace-aware version which is likely to be more useful in real situations.

If you need to add a new element at an exact position amongst several existing siblings (say, insert an element in between two existing children) you can get a reference to the latter sibling and use the [insertBefore](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node)) method.